# Mudar a visibilidade de um select

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho esse formulário, onde dependendo do que a pessoa escolher ira aparecer outro select para ela selecionar, porém dessa forma que eu fiz, não está aparecendo. Alguém sabe se isso não funciona pra select? porque eu tenho um pra mudar a visibilidade de um input e funciona normalmente. Ou se não pode usar 3 funções em um elemento apenas?

Aqui está o código JS que usei para mudar a visibilidade do select:

```
    function mostraCampogol(obj) {
      var select = document.getElementById('periodo');
      var txt = document.getElementById("turmagol");
      txt.style.visibility = (select.value == 'Golfinho') 
          ? "visible"
          : "hidden";  
    }
    function mostraCampopleno(obj) {
      var select = document.getElementById('periodo');
      var txt = document.getElementById("turmapleno");
      txt.style.visibility = (select.value == 'Pleno') 
          ? "visible"
          : "hidden";  
    }
    function mostraCamposenior(obj) {
      var select = document.getElementById('periodo');
      var txt = document.getElementById("turmasenior");
      txt.style.visibility = (select.value == 'Sênior') 
          ? "visible"
          : "hidden";  
    }
</script>
```

Aqui a parte do formulário em si:

```
<div class="form-group">                
          <label> Categoria <br />
            <select class="form-group" name="periodo" id="periodo" onchange="mostraCampogol(this.value);" onchange="mostraCampopleno(this.value);" onchange="mostraCamposenior(this.value);">
              <option></option>
              <option value="Golfinho">Golfinho/Júnior</option>
              <option value="Pleno">Pleno</option>
              <option value="Sênior">Sênior</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <select class="form-group" name="turmagol" id="turmagol" style="visibility: hidden;">
              <option value="Turma 1">Turma 1</option>
              <option value="Turma 2">Turma 2</option>
              <option value="Turma 3">Turma 3</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <select class="form-group" name="turmapleno" id="turmapleno" style="visibility: hidden;">
              <option value="Turma 4">Turma 4</option>
              <option value="Turma 5">Turma 5</option>
              <option value="Turma 6">Turma 6</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <select class="form-group" name="turmasenior" id="turmasenior" style="visibility: hidden;">
              <option value="Jovem">Jovem</option>
              <option value="Jovem">Jovem</option>
              <option value="Jovem">Jovem</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não deve definir [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange) 3 vezes, da forma como está **somente o primeiro** método (*mostraCampogol*) será disparado.

Você deve incluir as 3 chamadas de função em um único `onchange`:

```
<select class="form-group" name="periodo" id="periodo" onchange="mostraCampogol(this.value);mostraCampopleno(this.value);mostraCamposenior(this.value);">
```

Veja o exemplo abaixo funcionando:

```js
function mostraCampogol(obj) {
  var select = document.getElementById('periodo');
  var txt = document.getElementById("turmagol");
  txt.style.visibility = (select.value == 'Golfinho') 
      ? "visible"
      : "hidden";  
}

function mostraCampopleno(obj) {
  var select = document.getElementById('periodo');
  var txt = document.getElementById("turmapleno");
  txt.style.visibility = (select.value == 'Pleno') 
      ? "visible"
      : "hidden";  
}

function mostraCamposenior(obj) {
  var select = document.getElementById('periodo');
  var txt = document.getElementById("turmasenior");
  txt.style.visibility = (select.value == 'Sênior') 
      ? "visible"
      : "hidden";  
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">                
  <label> Categoria <br />
    <select class="form-group" name="periodo" id="periodo" onchange="mostraCampogol(this.value);mostraCampopleno(this.value);mostraCamposenior(this.value);">
      <option></option>
      <option value="Golfinho">Golfinho/Júnior</option>
      <option value="Pleno">Pleno</option>
      <option value="Sênior">Sênior</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
  <select class="form-group" name="turmagol" id="turmagol" style="visibility: hidden;">
      <option value="Turma 1">Turma 1</option>
      <option value="Turma 2">Turma 2</option>
      <option value="Turma 3">Turma 3</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
  <select class="form-group" name="turmapleno" id="turmapleno" style="visibility: hidden;">
      <option value="Turma 4">Turma 4</option>
      <option value="Turma 5">Turma 5</option>
      <option value="Turma 6">Turma 6</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
  <select class="form-group" name="turmasenior" id="turmasenior" style="visibility: hidden;">
      <option value="Jovem">Jovem</option>
      <option value="Jovem">Jovem</option>
      <option value="Jovem">Jovem</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Era realmente isso, muito obrigado pela ajuda!! Coisas básicas que estou deixando passar!